# Función de "lo" en "lo hambriento"

Tags: gramática, objetos-directos, clíticos

Leyendo Harry Potter un amigo extranjero notó esta oración:

> Harry miró su plato de oro vacío. Acababa de darse cuenta de *lo* hambriento que estaba. Los pasteles le parecían algo del pasado.

Me preguntó qué función tenía el *lo* ahí y por qué no podía ser:

> Acababa de darse cuenta de cuán hambriento estaba.

A lo cual no supe explicarle, ¿podrían darme una mano?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ambos son correctos. Es posible que usar "lo" en vez de "cuán" en esa oración tenga algo que ver con la frase exacta del inglés original, que de alguna manera sesgó al traductor a favor de esa palabra.  ¿En qué libro/capítulo se encuentra esa frase?

Comment: @SantiagoTórtora Estoy de acuerdo en que ambos sean correctos, pero eso no me basta para explicarle el porqué usar *lo* (los objetos indirectos y directos en el español siempre me son confusos). Por cierto, el pasaje original es **Harry looked down at his empty gold plate. He had only just realised how hungry he was. The pumpkin pasties seemed ages ago.** A mi parecer, ambas traducciones parecen perfectamente apropiadas para esa oración, no tendría preferencia de una sobre la otra.

Comment: ¿No os parece mas coloquial con "lo"?

Comment: En la pregunta enlazada aparece la entrada de la RAE que explica este uso de *lo*: "art. deter. n. Pondera el grado del adjetivo o el adverbio al que modifica. U. seguido de una subordinada introducida por que. *Ya sabes lo lentos que son. Admiro lo bien que trabaja.*" Si buscas artículo neutro en Google, hay bastante información de fácil acceso. Recomiendo [Hispanoteca](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Lo%20art%C3%ADculo%20neutro.htm) (leer a partir de "lo cualitativo").

Comment: Cuando uno lee "how hungry" lo primero que uno piensa es "lo". El tema es que "hunger" es non-countable, por lo que "how much hunger he was feeling" suena mal. Por lo tanto el traductor, inconcientemente tal vez, no quiso usar "cuán" que indica cantidad con una palabra que en inglés es no contable.